# Swift - On VC3 and wanting to unwind VC1 to VC2

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, scrollview, viewcontroller

I have a bookmark `viewController`. In that bookmark **VC** I got half of the top linked with **VC1**, when I press on a button in bookmark it will take me to VC1 and the position that I told it to go with this code,

```
@IBAction func Home2(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (ScrollView != nil){
        ScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(8, 8, 239, 43), animated: true)
}

}

 @IBAction func goHome2(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    Home2(self)
}
```

I linked these codes from the **story boards**.   For the rest of the bottom half on my bookmark **VC** I have it for my **VC2**, i'll show you the piece of code for the **VC2** thats linked up with in storyboard and another code that lets me go on to **VC2**,

```
@IBAction func returnTo3(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("back in the ViewController3")
}

@IBAction func secondHome_1(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (secondScrollView != nil){
        secondScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(8, 8, 359, 483), animated: true)

    }
 }

@IBAction func secondHome3_1(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // Call the home method to position the scrollView
    secondHome_1(self)
}
```

Now you know how I can get to my position that I want to from bookmark VC, the part I'm struggling at is when I'm on **VC1** and I go to my bookmarks and go the bottom half of my bookmarks and press on the bottom thats for **VC2**, it dose not let me go to **VC2** position I want to, it keeps me at **VC1** in same position.

Is there a way I can go from pressing on bookmarks in my **VC1** and going to the bottom half of it and click on **VC2** button and go from **VC1** to **VC2** position?

These are some pictures to make you understand more,

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are these embedded in a Navigation Controller?

Comment: Yes they are embedded in Navigation Controller.